# Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̊ (U+030A)

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, mendeley

I use Mendeley and Overleaf version of LaTeX in browser.

I get the Error:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̊ (U+030A)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.28 ...rundvandet mod forurening og forringelse}}
                                                  ,
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter 

[25]) [26]
\tf@toc=\write5
\openout5 = `output.toc'.
```

I know it's because I use the charachter Å, but I don't know how to inlcude it. I write in English but my references are sometimes in Danish, like in this case.

Here is the bibtex from Mendeley:

[image]

And here is the output in pdfLatex

[image]

And in my preamble I have the packages for language and symbols:

```latex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[english]{babel}                
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
\usepackage{ragged2e,anyfontsize}           
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Try using `\r{a}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add the code from Mendeley rather than a screenshot. Screenshots are only for showing LaTeX output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm on support staff at Overleaf.)

It looks like this glyph is entered in Mendeley as a combining accent mark (U+030A) plus the base character, A. Overleaf takes the .bib file as exported by Mendeley; we don't perform any processing on the file we receive from Mendeley.

The inputenc package isn't set up to handle these combining accent marks by default; this leads to the error. To fix this, re-type the character in Mendeley as a pre-composed accented character: `Å` (U+00C5). Then refresh your .bib file in Overleaf.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot.